# Uncaught Error: react-apollo only supports a query, subscription, or a mutation per HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to wrap my `Chat` component with two queries and one mutation using `compose`.

However, I'm still getting the following error in the console:

> **Uncaught Error:** `react-apollo` only supports a query, subscription, or a mutation per HOC. `[object Object]` had 2 queries, 0 subscriptions and 0 mutations. You can use '`compose`' to join multiple operation types to a component

Here are my queries and the export statement:

```
// this query seems to cause the issue
const findConversations = gql`
    query allConversations($customerId: ID!) {
        allConversations(filter: {
          customerId: $customerId
        })
    } {
        id
    }
`

const createMessage = gql`
    mutation createMessage($text: String!, $conversationId: ID!) {
        createMessage(text: $text, conversationId: $conversationId) {
            id
            text
        }
    }
`

const allMessages = gql`
    query allMessages($conversationId: ID!) {
        allMessages(filter: {
        conversation: {
        id: $conversationId
        }
        })
        {
            text
            createdAt
        }
    }
`

export default compose(
  graphql(findConversations, {name: 'findConversationsQuery'}),
  graphql(allMessages, {name: 'allMessagesQuery'}),
  graphql(createMessage, {name : 'createMessageMutation'})
)(Chat)
```

Apparently, the issue is with the `findConversations` query. If I comment it out, I don't get the error and the component loads properly:

```
// this works
export default compose(
  // graphql(findConversations, {name: 'findConversationsQuery'}),
  graphql(allMessages, {name: 'allMessagesQuery'}),
  graphql(createMessage, {name : 'createMessageMutation'})
)(Chat)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

By the way, I also have a subscription set up on the `allMessagesQuery`, in case that's relevant:

```
componentDidMount() {

  this.newMessageSubscription = this.props.allMessagesQuery.subscribeToMore({
    document: gql`
        subscription {
            createMessage(filter: {
            conversation: {
            id: "${this.props.conversationId}"
            }
            }) {
                text
                createdAt
            }
        }
    `,
    updateQuery: (previousState, {subscriptionData}) => {
       ...
    },
    onError: (err) => console.error(err),
  })

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `findConversationsQuery` is actually two queries. This one:

```
query allConversations($customerId: ID!) {
    allConversations(filter: {
      customerId: $customerId
    })
}
```

And this one:

```
{
    id
}
```

The entire query needs to be enclosed between a single pair of opening and closing brackets.

I think what you meant to write is:

```
query allConversations($customerId: ID!) {
    allConversations(filter: { customerId: $customerId }){
        id
    }
}
```